# Any advice how to improve my implementation?

Tags: java, spring, java-stream

this is a part of my code below. When I use the for loop (commented out) - it works. When I use this stream - it kind of works but then behaves badly on a method I would never expect it to.

```
        Spravochnik spr = new Spravochnik();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmeta = rs.getMetaData();
        List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<String>> valuesInRows = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        int columnCount = rsmeta.getColumnCount();

        IntStream.range(0, rsmeta.getColumnCount()).forEach(i -> {
            try {
                columnNames.add(rsmeta.getColumnName(i));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

//      for(int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++){
//          columnNames.add(rsmeta.getColumnName(column));
//      }
```

Guess I just have my implementation wrong. Any advice how to improve here? Thanks!

Comment: Obviously in the stream, you're starting from 0 while in the for cycle, you start from 1. In a ResultSet, columns are indexed from 1.

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, rsmeta.getColumnCount())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful what numbers within looping or streaming are included and what numbers are not.

- [`IntStream::range(int startInclusive, int endExclusive)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) matches interval `<a, b)`
- [`IntStream::rangeClosed(int startInclusive, int endInclusive)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) matches interval `<a, b>`

Note the first number is always inclusive and since you loop from `1`, you want toant to start the `Stream` from `1` as well:

```
IntStream.range(1, rsmeta.getColumnCount()).forEach(i -> {
    // ...
});
```

Finally, the benefit of the `Stream` usage here is rather questionable. Actually, there is **no** benefit at all. I highly recommend to stick with the `for-loop` in this use-case:

```
for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
    columnNames.add(rsmeta.getColumnName(column));
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to maybe create the columnNames List on the fly like that, not only populate? Is it possible to improve?

Comment: Better would be...`.map(i -> rsmeta.getColumnName(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());`. However, I am not sure I get your question now.

Comment: `List<String> columnNames = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, rsmeta.getColumnCount()).map(i -> rsmeta.getColumnName(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());` says type mismatch can't from string to int...and I need to use the index inside getColumnName...sorry if it's a sill,y question I've just started learning streams

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IntStream.range(1, rsmeta.getColumnCount()+1)` which will give you the column numbers starting from 1 till the total count.